# Data Vault, Links between hubs and lookup tables

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, data-vault

I have an entity in my data vault that has a hub, satellite tables, and links to other entities with hubs. I have a separate entity in my data vault that only serves a singular purpose of being a lookup tables. The lookup table is a simple translation from unique code number to description.

I'm curious if it would be terrible practice to have "link" tables that associate Business keys from Hubs to the Codes for the Lookup table. The only other alternative I see is to turn this lookup table entity into a hub that holds all of the code numbers and a satellite table with all of the descriptions. This seems like it would be inefficient and result in one additional query every time, rather than having a lookup table.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [Reference table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_vault_modeling#Reference_tables) for your lookups. Reference tables break the Data Vault model in a very specific way: essentially by allowing a join from a satellite column (code) to the reference table (code) that holds the description and/or any additional information. This allows you to keep your code column in your satellite table and avoid an unnecessary link relationship.

[Additional documentation](http://roelantvos.com/blog/?p=698)